# RoR The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create new directory via "Commad Prompt with RoR" and this is what i got:

```
$ cd ~/rails_projects
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the rails project first by `rails new` command.

```
$ cd ~
$ rails new rails_projects
$ cd rails_projects
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's didn't help - same error after `$ cd ~`

Comment: @user1726862 If you failed to new the project, of course there is no directory you could cd into.

Answer (score 0):

break first command into two seperate commands

```
$ cd ~
$ rails new rails_projects
```

& then

```
$ cd rails_projects
```